# Making switch statement in method loop

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

```
 void menu(){ 
    System.out.println("1. Take Quiz");
    System.out.println("2. Quiz Results");
    System.out.println("3. Performance Comment");
    System.out.println("4. Exit");
    System.out.print("Choose from the above:");
    byte menu = Keyboard.readByte();
    switch(menu){

        case 1 : 
        takeQuiz();
        break;

        case 2 :
        quizResults();
        break;

        case 3 :
        performanceComment();
        break;

        case 4 : 
        exit();

    }
}
```

I want to make this code loop so that if the user inputs case 1 , case 1 will appear but afterwards the whole menu comes back up again. Same with case 2 etc.
Should I use a loop and if yes how?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Learn to use loops with these pages of Oracle's Java Tutorials: [The while and do-while Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) and [The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: Try it first. [Edit] your question  when you get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both **while** or **for** loops:
**while loop**:

```
void menu() {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("1. Take Quiz");
        System.out.println("2. Quiz Results");
        System.out.println("3. Performance Comment");
        System.out.println("4. Exit");
        System.out.print("Choose from the above:");
        byte menu = Keyboard.readByte();
        switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                takeQuiz();
            case 2:
                quizResults();
            case 3:
                performanceComment();
            case 4:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**for loop:**

```
void menu() {
    for (;;) {
        System.out.println("1. Take Quiz");
        System.out.println("2. Quiz Results");
        System.out.println("3. Performance Comment");
        System.out.println("4. Exit");
        System.out.print("Choose from the above:");
        byte menu = Keyboard.readByte();
        switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                takeQuiz();
            case 2:
                quizResults();
            case 3:
                performanceComment();
            case 4:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Both ways are using infinite loops.
Break keyword terminates the loop.
[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) you can read more about break keyword.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

add a boolean flag at begin and a while loop until the user select 4:

```
void menu(){
    boolean mustRun = true; 
    while(mustRun){
        System.out.println("1. Take Quiz");
        System.out.println("2. Quiz Results");
        System.out.println("3. Performance Comment");
        System.out.println("4. Exit");
        System.out.print("Choose from the above:");
        byte menu = Keyboard.readByte();
        switch(menu){
            case 1 : 
            takeQuiz();
            break;
            case 2 :
            quizResults();
            break;
            case 3 :
            performanceComment();
            break;
            case 4 : 
            mustRun = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```